# =default in class constructors

Tags: c++, c++11

I know that making a constructor like this:

```
foo()=delete;
```

will make it unnaccesible, but what about:

```
foo()=default;
```

? I saw this sometimes, but I dont know whatit means!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Explicitly_defaulted_and_deleted_special_member_functions

Comment: -1: "This question does not show any research effort"

Comment: It might be hard to google because `default` has another meaning (and this new one was only added in C++11).

Comment: I think that this is a good reference case question, regardless of whether much research was done here. Personally, I learned something today.

Comment: @afishwhoswimsaround: But the user knows it's a C++11 feature since he tagged it as such.  It is not useful to ask one question for each new C++ feature, and there are many good resources that explain those in detail.

Comment: @FerdinandBeyer: There is more to `default` than catches the eye, as an example, the first few answers got it wrong by stating that it is equivalent to `foo() {}` --it is not. One of the old answers vaguely goes over by avoiding the comparison...

Comment: @DavidRodríguez: Bad, poorly-researched questions can still lead to good answers. That doesn't *excuse* them.

Answer (score 8):

Here's how `default` is useful. Recall that in order to be POD ("plain old data"), a class type *must* have a *trivial default constructor*:

```
struct this_is_pod
{
     int a;
     double b;
};

struct this_is_not_pod
{
    char c;
    float d;
    this_is_not_pod() { }
};
```

However, what if we *would* like to provide a means for initializing the class members in some non-trivial way? Just writing a non-default constructor doesn't work:

```
struct foo
{
    int m;
    void * p;
    foo(double q, Bar & o) : m(magic(q), p(o.gizmo(m, q)) { }
};
```

Now `foo` is *not* POD, because it lacks a default constructor altogether. Adding our own default constructor, like `foo() {}`, still doesn't work because now the default constructor isn't trivial. C++11 comes to the rescue with `default`:

```
struct foo
{
    int m;
    void * p;
    foo(double q, Bar & o) : m(magic(q), p(o.gizmo(m, q)) { }
    foo() = default; // trivial!
};

static_assert(std::is_pod<foo>::value, "You will never see this message.");
```

Comment: this doesn't address what exactly a "trivial" constructor actually means, i.e. why =default is different than {}

Comment: @FellowsheeL Because the standard says so. A constructor that's defaulted in its first declaration is user-declared, but not user-defined.

Answer (score 4):

In C++03, if you don't define any constructor, the compiler generates a default constructor for you. If you do define some other constructor, however, the compiler doesn't generate a default constructor (at all).

The `=default` tells the compiler to generate a default constructor even though you've explicitly defined some other constructor as well. This was added in C++11 -- there was no  way to do the same in C++03 (or 98). Any constructor you define explicitly differs at least a little from what the compiler generates by default.

Answer (score 0):

It tells the compile to guess a default constructor, meanign one with no arguments. This is what the compilers usually do if no "delete" is given. It is introduced in C++11 as well as the delete option.

Answer (score 0):

Compiler will implicitly generate a default constructor, *unless* you explicitly defined *any* constructor yourself.

The `foo() = default;` simply instructs the compiler to generate the default constructor even if you defined a non-default one. It's *mostly* the same as `foo() {}` (but see [Kerrek SB's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10484903/533120)).

Comment: I am not sure on whether it is *exactly* equivalent to `foo(){}`. There are cases where the two might differ, as for example with `struct s { int x; }` the *default* compiler generated (as I understand it) would be `constexpr foo() {}`, which means that `s().x` is a `constexpr`... would have to verify this anyway

Comment: It's *not* the same as `foo() {}`. The latter isn't trivial.

Comment: @KerrekSB It appears you are right, section 12.1.5: _"A default constructor is trivial if it is neither user-provided nor..."_. What's the practical difference?